# How to get the area from polygon?

Tags: leaflet

i try to get area from polygon using this code:

```
//leaflet.js attach
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
crossorigin=""></script>
........
........
and after some code:


var area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(polygon .getLatLngs());
```

But , i can't find  geodesicArea function in( error:"L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea is not a function") . What i need to attach to get geodesicArea function?

Comment: A quick search reveals https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/ext/GeometryUtil.js